# I need help in using double Promises in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

Here is the code that I tried.

```
  // To get base64 code of file
  const toBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloaded = () => resolve(reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, ''));
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  })

  // To make an array of files
  const getAttachments = async files => {
    let documents;
    try {
      documents = files.map(async file => {
        let base64 = await toBase64(file)
        return {
          doc: base64,
          documentName: file.name,
          documentType: file.type
        }
      })
    } catch {
      console.error('Failed to get files as base64')
    }
    return Promise.resolve(documents)
  }
```

And I just tried to get an object array as a result by using the above 2 functions.
Like the following;

```
getAttachments(Array.from(event.target.files)).then(documents => {
  console.info(documents)
}
```

But the result is

[Logged out result in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nyBi.png)

I'd love to know how I can get what I want.
Thanks.

Comment: `documents = await Promise.all(files.map(async file =>` etc

Comment: Thanks for your comment but nothing is logging out in the console.

Comment: you possibly did it wrong ... how about the answer below? did that work?

Comment: It is not logging out anything as well.

Comment: Hi @Bravo, thanks for your time.  I can see what the problem is.  I've changed `reader.onloaded` to `reader.onload` in `toBase64()` method and it's working now.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense, and explains the lack of output since no promises would resolve ever :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning an array of promises try returning an array of resolved promise using the `await` keyword.

try this

```js
const getAttachments = async files => {
  let documents;
  try {
    documents = files.map(async file => {
      let base64 = await toBase64(file)
      return {
        doc: base64,
        documentName: file.name,
        documentType: file.type
      }
    })
    
    return await Promise.all(documents);
  } catch {
    console.error('Failed to get files as base64')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is no logging out in the console when I run this function.
`getAttachments(files).then(documents => { console.info(documents) }`

Comment: perhaps `files` is empty array @baymax88 or perhaps you're filtered out `info` logs ... try `console.log` instead of `console.info`

Comment: by the way `return await Promise.all(documents);` ... just do `return Promise.all(documents);`

Comment: I added `console.log(files)` before the `let documents;` and it's logging out the `files` but nothing is logged out as a result yet.

Comment: what does `console.log(documents)` before the `return` output @baymax88

Comment: The problem was in `toBase64()` method. Thanks, guys!